# Misconception regarding Master and Home document types

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I currently have these **Document Types**:

```
Master
    Home
    News
    About
```

I allow **Home** at root, so when I visit `/` it will show my home, instead of going to `/home`. Then I create a new Content for Home. That means my **Content**/page layout looks like this:

```
Home
    News
    About
```

Since I want all my pages to be `/news` and `/about`, but still have `/` be my **Home**, I therefore allow **News** and **About** to be children of **Home** (in the permissions tab). This is great and all, because I can then create properties on my **Home** Document Type, which the other document types will inherit (such as SEO).

Well, both great and bad. If I want my **Home** page to have properties that none of the other pages will inherit, I cannot do that now, because all the other pages inherits from my **Home** Document Type.

How am I supposed to achieve this:

- Have a **Master.cshtml** file, which has `@RenderBody()`
- Make a property on **Home** which will not be inherited by all the other Document Types
- Make sure `/` is my **Home** content page

The only way I can think about this, is by allowing my **Master** Document Type at root, then replace my **Home** Document Type with **Master** and have the same structure as now, but basically have **Home** as a child of **Master** (in the content page). This would mean `/` is set to the **Master** content page, which I do not want. However, URL rewriting `/home` to `/` should solve my issue, right?

Is there a better way? Is this *the* way to go? Let me know how you guys would structure a page like this, so I can create properties for all pages and while separating **Home** from the rest of the pages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should use **composition** of document type instead of "nested inheritance". This new feature has been made exactly to solve this kind of problem:

You can add to every document type the SEO document type to add the SEO tab, but add some specific properties only to some document types. No need to change the tree in the content section.

For example you can create these document types:

- seo (only used for composition in other document types)
- shared (only used for composition in other document types)
- home (with composition of  seo + shared ) +  some specific fields  for this document type
- news (with composition of  seo + shared) + some *other* specific fields for this
- about (with composition of  seo and no need for the shared for this particular document type)

*Note that these are flat on the document type tree and there is no need for master document type because you will add everything in common via composition and not inheritance.*

The content tree will look exactly the same:

```
Home
    News
    About
```

Take a look at http://letswritecode.net/articles/document-type-compositions-in-umbraco/ for some examples

Comment: I have read and understood the concept of compositions, but I am unable to see how I am going to implement this. Do I create a new document type for each composition I want to use? Like a composition for SEO, composition for common things that appear on all pages, etc., then go to each document type and use those compositions?

Comment: Yes exactly, so you have full control on each document type. This might seem like a burden at first sight, but you will get used to it and love it the first time that you will have  to add a specific property to a document type and not to others. The 'tree' on the document type section should be flat or almost flat (you can mix inheritance and composition at some degree if you want)

Comment: What's the difference between doing a site using only compositions and one just using inheritance? I could imagine doing the idea of inheritance with compositions is kind of... annoying? Adding the same composition over and over again to each document type. What if I use Robs answer with inheritance, but I use compositions for document types which share the same properties (yet not all share them)? I guess that would be a good overall solution.

Comment: Having used both composition and inheritance in a lot of websites I now use composition only because it's more powerful. It's just more few clicks, not really annoying. Also you don't need to create a Master node in the content section even if you have a Master document type in the document type section..just create a "home" node

Comment: What if I want my **Home** document type to have different properties than the rest? Would I simply put those properties into compositions instead of directly onto the document type? Seems weird to do it like that.

Comment: `+ some specific fields for the home`. Do these go into a composition called home? If I were to follow your exact words and structure, I would end up with **News** and **About** inheriting from Home.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143400/discussion-between-eyescream-and-mortenmoulder).

Comment: I think I know where I got off. I was thinking Document Types the whole time, where I should've been thinking Content Nodes. That's definitely my bad.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use an Umbraco internal redirect to display the **Home** page content whenever the root `/` URL is requested.

Add a new Content Picker property to your **Master** DocumentType and give it the alias `umbracoInternalRedirectId`.  This is a [reserved property alias](http://www.wiliam.com.au/wiliam-blog/sydney-web-design-umbraco-reserved-properties-and-their-usage), much like `umbracoNaviHide` and `umbracoRedirect`, and it will cause the selected page's content to be displayed without performing a URL redirect.

[image]

On your **Master** page select the **Home** page using your new property.  Now whenever you browse to `/` the **Home** page content will be displayed.

[image]

Your **Home** page will still be accessible via the `/home` URL so you should either use a canonical tag to prevent duplication of content or you could implement a URL rewrite from `/home` to `/`.

Comment: Why do you actually need a Master (or Website) content node in the first place?  Can you place your Home node at the root, and then have all the other nodes directly under that?  You shouldn't need to worry about internal redirects or anything like that.